# Shift + Esc doesn't work on MacBook Pro with touch bar

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

There are some apps that use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> combination. But it's doesn't work when I use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> on touch bar. Apps behave as just the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button pressed. When I connect external keyboard or even use the embedded keyboard viewer <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> works!

Karabiner Event Viewer shows keycode 41 for <kbd>Esc</kbd> both for touch bar button and regular button pressed on an external keyboard. Seems that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> should work in both cases but it isn't.

Any ideas what can be done in order to make the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> work with button on touch bar? I usually use this combination in Slack and IntelliJ Idea applications. E.g. in Slack <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> marks all messages as read. That's how I check combination working or not.

Comment: A workaround would be to try to map shift/ESC (or another shortcut) with touchbar to those actions.